# PHP foreach - how to traverse unknown elements

Tags: php

I have an array similar to this:

```
$body = array(
  "object" => "page",
  "entry" => array(
    "0" => array(
      "id" => 153125381133,
      "time" => 1438292065,
      "changes" => array(
        "0" => array(
          "field" => "leadgen",
          "value" => array(
            "leadgen_id" => 123123123123,
            "page_id" => 123123123,
            "form_id" => 12312312312,
            "adgroup_id" => 12312312312,
            "ad_id" => 12312312312,
            "created_time" => 1440120384
          )
        ),
        "1" => array(
          "field" => "leadgen",
          "value" => array(
            "leadgen_id" => 123123123124,
            "page_id" => 123123123,
            "form_id" => 12312312312,
            "adgroup_id" => 12312312312,
            "ad_id" => 12312312312,
            "created_time" => 1440120384
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

I would like to use a foreach loop to extract each "leadgen_id" field, but don't know how to traverse unknown elements:

```
foreach ($body['entry'][THIS VALUE COULD BE 0 or 1 or 2...etc...]['changes'][THIS COULD BE 0 to 20]['value']['leadgen_id'] as $leadgenid)
{  code..... }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Go recursive to get them.

Comment: Please remove the "json" tag. There isn't anything related to JSON in this question. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. All you have here is the data structure and some code that processes it. No text representation of if of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) for this. See snippet below for a commented demo. This will output:
array(2) {
[0]=>
int(123123123123)
[1]=>
int(123123123124)
}

```
function extractLeadgen($data, array &$leadgens):array
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            // Recurse and descend into child array.
            extractLeadgen($value, $leadgens);
        }
        else
        {
            // Reached non-array value. If its key is the column we want, record its value.
            if ($key === 'leadgen_id')
                // Adding to array by reference (&).
                $leadgens[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

$leadgens = [];
extractLeadgen($body, $leadgens);
var_dump($leadgens);
/*
Outputs:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(123123123123)
  [1]=>
  int(123123123124)
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This would recurse over it:

```
$results = array();

function recurseandextract($thearray,&$res){
    
    foreach($thearray as $key => $value){
        if( is_array($thearray[$key]) ){
            recurseandextract($thearray[$key],$res);
        }elseif($key == "leadgen_id"){
            array_push($res,$value);
        }
    }
}

recurseandextract($body,$results);
print serialize($results);
```